# SQL ZOO Window LAG #8

Tags: sql, window-functions, lag

Question: For each country that has had at last 1000 new cases in a single day, show the date of the peak number of new cases.

[Here is a few sample data of the covid table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf3JD.png).
What I write:

```
SELECT name,date,MAX(confirmed-lag) AS PeakNew 
FROM(
    SELECT name, DATE_FORMAT(whn,'%Y-%m-%d') date, confirmed,
    LAG(confirmed, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY whn) lag  
    FROM covid 
    ORDER BY  confirmed
) temp
GROUP BY name
HAVING PeakNew>=1000
ORDER BY PeakNew DESC;
```

The result I got is weird, PeakNew seems correct, but the related date is not.

[My answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lujm.png)

[The right answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoE7E.png)

Anyone can help to get the right answer? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Anna and welcome! Posting the query was a good first step. It would help to add some data ( a few rows), and the schema of the covid table and what the results are.

Comment: Hi Spyros, thank you for your advice. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

The below query works perfectly fine for me. Though the dates and values are correct, the output will say otherwise as the order is different. Here the order is by date, then by name.

```
SELECT z1.name, DATE_FORMAT(c.dt,'%Y-%m-%d'), z1.nc
FROM 

(
SELECT z.name, MAX(z.nc) AS 'mx'
FROM (
SELECT DATE(whn) AS 'dt', name, confirmed - LAG(confirmed,1) OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY DATE(whn) ASC) AS 'nc'
FROM covid ) z
WHERE z.nc >= 1000
GROUP BY z.name
) z1

INNER JOIN

(
SELECT DATE(whn) AS 'dt', name, confirmed - LAG(confirmed,1) OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY DATE(whn) ASC) AS 'nc'
FROM covid
) c

ON c.nc = z1.mx
AND c.name = z1.name

ORDER BY 2 ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

The `date` value in the outer query doesn't correspond to row where `MAX(confirmed-lag)` is found - it's just a random date value within that group. Check out the section titled, "The ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY Issue" in this blog post: https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/05/13/solve-query-failures-regarding-only_full_group_by-sql-mode/ for more information.

I used the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to get the entire row corresponding to the maximum new cases. However, my final result wasn't ordered the way the answer was, and there's no specification to how it should be ordered, so I still didn't get that satisfying happy emoji.

Answer (score 0):

You need to self join to obtain the date on which the max count occurred:

```
WITH CTE1 as
(SELECT name,DATE_FORMAT(whn, "%Y-%m-%d") as date,
   confirmed - LAG(confirmed, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY DATE(whn)) as increase
 FROM covid
ORDER BY whn),
CTE2 AS
(SELECT name, MAX(increase) as max_increase
FROM CTE1
WHERE increase >999
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY date)
SELECT c1.name,c1.date,c2.max_increase as peakNewCases
FROM CTE1 as c1
JOIN CTE2 as c2
ON c1.name=c2.name AND c1.increase=c2.max_increase
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE1 as
(SELECT name, DATE_FORMAT(whn,'%Y-%m-%d') as date_form, confirmed - LAG(confirmed,1) OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY whn) AS newcases
 FROM covid
ORDER BY name,whn) 


SELECT name, date_form, newcases FROM
(
SELECT name, date_form, newcases, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY newcases DESC) as rank
FROM CTE1
WHERE newcases > 999
) cte2
WHERE rank =1
```